# same properties of NSURLSessionConfiguration and NSURLRequest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I see that in official documentation, NSURLSessionConfiguration and NSURLRequest share some same or similar properties. For example, NSURLRequestCachePolicy, networkServiceType, timeOurInterval etc. How come? Which side is in higher priority?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/):

> An `NSURLSessionConfiguration` object defines the behavior and policies
>   to use when uploading and downloading data using an NSURLSession
>   object. When uploading or downloading data, creating a configuration
>   object is always the first step you must take. You use this object to
>   configure the timeout values, caching policies, connection
>   requirements, and other types of information that you intend to use
>   with your `NSURLSession` object.

**Importantly:**

> NOTE
>
> In some cases, the policies defined in this configuration may be
>   overridden by policies specified by an `NSURLRequest` object provided
>   for a task. Any policy specified on the request object is respected
>   unless the session’s policy is more restrictive. For example, if the
>   session configuration specifies that cellular networking should not be
>   allowed, the `NSURLRequest` object cannot request cellular networking.

So, essentially, `NSURLSessionConfiguration` sets the properties at `NSURLSession` which can be overridden by `NSURLRequest` object.

Comment: You are always welcome @WhiteWhite. Glad it helped :)... Cheers!

Comment: Correct. The priority of the URL is higher, but it can *never* do something that session itself isn't allowing. ie:

If the session has caching disabled , then you can't request it to cache. 

However if the session has caching enabled, then you can for a URL, request it to *not* be cached